# Has someone implemented page objects using wd(Javascript bindings)?

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation

Since WD https://github.com/admc/wd has created its own wrappers for all the webdriver APIs, has someone found a way of implementing page objects using WD and Appium? Any pointers in this direction would be greatly helpful.